# Errors while installing rgbdslam on NVIDIA Jetson TK1

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

we are trying to install rbgdsalm on NVIDIA Jetson TK1 by following the given steps in https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2

these are the given steps

***Prepare Workspace***

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash

mkdir -p ~/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src

cd ~/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src

catkin_init_workspace

cd ~/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/

catkin_make

source devel/setup.bash
```

***Get RGBDSLAM***

```
cd ~/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src

wget -q http://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2/archive/indigo.zip

unzip -q indigo.zip

cd ~/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/
```

***Install***

```
rosdep update

rosdep install rgbdslam
```

we could successfully complete up to the above step but executing the "catkin_make " gives this error

```
  [  8%] Building CXX object rgbdslam_v2-indigo/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/moc_openni_listener.cxx.o
c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,

with preprocessed source if appropriate.

See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs> for instructions.

make[2]: *** [rgbdslam_v2-indigo/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/moc_openni_listener.cxx.o] Error 4

make[1]: *** [rgbdslam_v2-indigo/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/all] Error 2

make: *** [all] Error 2

Invoking "make -j1 -l1" failed
```

I have attempted by enabling a 4GB swap file on the Jetson's storage and again tried with "catkin_make" command. But again en counted with following errors

```
[ 54%] Building CXX object rgbdslam_v2-indigo/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/node.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:128:0,
                 from /usr/include/GL/glut.h:17,
                 from /home/ubuntu/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2-indigo/src/glviewer.cpp:24:
/usr/include/GL/gl.h:138:17: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef double GLdouble'
 typedef double  GLdouble; /* double precision float */
                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/qt4/QtOpenGL/QtOpenGL:5:0,
                 from /home/ubuntu/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2-indigo/src/glviewer.cpp:22:
/usr/include/qt4/QtOpenGL/qgl.h:85:17: error: 'GLdouble' has a previous declaration as 'typedef GLfloat GLdouble'
 typedef GLfloat GLdouble;
                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/GL/gl.h:2059:0,
                 from /usr/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:128,
                 from /usr/include/GL/glut.h:17,
                 from /home/ubuntu/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2-indigo/src/glviewer.cpp:24:
/usr/include/GL/glext.h:468:19: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef ptrdiff_t GLsizeiptr'
 typedef ptrdiff_t GLsizeiptr;
                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/qt4/QtOpenGL/qgl.h:79:0,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/QtOpenGL/QtOpenGL:5,
                 from /home/ubuntu/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2-indigo/src/glviewer.cpp:22:
/usr/include/GLES2/gl2.h:69:25: error: 'GLsizeiptr' has a previous declaration as 'typedef khronos_ssize_t GLsizeiptr'
 typedef khronos_ssize_t GLsizeiptr;
                         ^
In file included from /usr/include/GL/gl.h:2059:0,
                 from /usr/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:128,
                 from /usr/include/GL/glut.h:17,
                 from /home/ubuntu/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2-indigo/src/glviewer.cpp:24:
/usr/include/GL/glext.h:469:19: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef ptrdiff_t GLintptr'
 typedef ptrdiff_t GLintptr;
                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/qt4/QtOpenGL/qgl.h:79:0,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/QtOpenGL/QtOpenGL:5,
                 from /home/ubuntu/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2-indigo/src/glviewer.cpp:22:
/usr/include/GLES2/gl2.h:70:26: error: 'GLintptr' has a previous declaration as 'typedef khronos_intptr_t GLintptr'
 typedef khronos_intptr_t GLintptr;
                          ^
make[2]: *** [rgbdslam_v2-indigo/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/glviewer.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [rgbdslam_v2-indigo/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
make: INTERNAL: Exiting with 5 jobserver tokens available; should be 4!
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232225/errors-while-installing-rgbdslam-on-nvidia-jetson-tk1/) by [Nirmala Madusanka](https://answers.ros.org/users/26634/nirmala-madusanka/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a good chance the compiler is running out of memory, especially on a limited embedded platform. Have you enabled any swap? If not, please do so and try again.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2016-04-20**:
Yes, sounds like [this issue](https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2/issues/29)

**Comment by [Nirmala Madusanka](https://answers.ros.org/users/26634/nirmala-madusanka/) on 2016-05-06**:
Thank you very much and I'll try to do so. But can you tell me how to enable a swap on Jetson's storage. Because the OS is flashing through a host machine using the Jet Pack L4T. In this procedure there is no chance to enable a swap(as I know). Thanks again

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2016-05-09**:
No idea, sorry.

**Comment by [Nirmala Madusanka](https://answers.ros.org/users/26634/nirmala-madusanka/) on 2016-05-09**:
I have attempted by creating a 4GB swap file inside the Nvidia Jetson TK1 and tried with "catkin_make" command. but now it gave me following errors in consecutive 3 times.
1.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4Z7AAjuMafBQ1F5Uk9hTjdyR00

2.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4Z7AAjuMafBMGY1c0FpUT

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-05-09**:
In general: for console text, please just *copy* it into your question. If those screenshots are removed / become inaccessible, we won't ever know what issue you encountered. Please *edit* your original question with the new information.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-05-09**:
As to your problem: the `CMakeLists.txt` of the package is most likely unconditionally adding the `-mfpmath=sse` flag to the `CXX` flags. The compiler you are using does not appear to support that flag, so it prints an error and exits. Remove the flag, or replace with an equivalent.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2016-05-09**:
The 4GB solved the memory problem. The compiler errors in the lates log is something different. Please create a new question for it, because it would be confusing to later readers to merge these problems in a single question/answer.

**Comment by [Nirmala Madusanka](https://answers.ros.org/users/26634/nirmala-madusanka/) on 2016-05-09**:
Alright Felix, I will create a new question. thanks a lot